# Why does "Scenario Outline" generate new steps for me?

Tags: java, cucumber

I have the below **Gerkin** file:

```
Feature: Create a new insurance contract.
  As a customer, I should be able to register for insurance.

  Scenario: The customer should be able to register for an insurance.
    Given I am in the starting page
    And The car is already insured
    And I want to have an insurance from today
    When I click on Weiter button
    Then It asks for the owner of the car
    And I am not the ownner of the car
    And the car is new when i purchase it
    When I click on Weiter
    Then It navigates to selectVehicle
    When I click on the "brand" of my car in the list
    Then I am asked to specify the model of my car in selectModel
    When I click on the "model" of my car
    Then I am asked to specify the body type of the car
    When I click on the "body type" of the car
    Then I am asked to specify the Fuel Type of the car
    When I select the "fuel"
    Then I am asked to specify the horse power of the car
    When I select the "power" of engine
    Then I am asked specify Engine
    When I select the "engine" of the car
    Then I am asked to specify the registeration date
    When I specify the registeration date
    Then I am asked to specify my birth date

  Scenario Outline: The customer should be able to register for an insurance.
    Given I am in the starting page
    And The car is already insured
    And I want to have an insurance from today
    When I click on Weiter button
    Then It asks for the owner of the car
    And I am not the ownner of the car
    And the car is new when i purchase it
    When I click on Weiter
    Then It navigates to selectVehicle
    When I click on the <brand> of my car in the list
    Then I am asked to specify the model of my car in selectModel
    When I click on the <model> of my car
    Then I am asked to specify the body type of the car
    When I click on the <body-type> of the car
    Then I am asked to specify the Fuel Type of the car
    When I select the <fuel>
    Then I am asked to specify the horse power of the car
    When I select the <engine-power> of engine
    Then I am asked specify Engine
    When I select the <engine> of the car
    Then I am asked to specify the registeration date
    When I specify the registeration date
    Then I am asked to specify my birth date

    Examples: 
      | brand | model | body-type | fuel   | engine-power    | engine              |
      | BMW   | 1er   | Cabrio    | Benzin | 105 kW / 143 PS | HSN: 0005, TSN: AMP |
```

**I have already implemented the steps of this file.**

When i run the test, it first runs the `Scenario` and then it runs the `Scenario Outline`.ُSo, the test runs 2 times, meanwhile i expect it only get run once and it only executes `Scenario Outline` with the below parameters:

```
 | BMW   | 1er   | Cabrio    | Benzin | 105 kW / 143 PS | HSN: 0005, TSN: AMP|
```

It also executes the `Scenario Outline` (in second try) but it generates the new steps for me, which is a surprised, since the steps are already there.

My questions are:

1. Shouldn't it only execute my `Scenario Outline`?
2. How can i fix this issue?
3. Why it cannot find my steps?

Comment: You are missing quotes in your scenario outline. Try replacing `<brand>` with `"<brand>"`.

Comment: Yes, now it finds the steps, so your solution solves one problem. but it still runs the `Scenario`. Any idea? @mpkorstanje

Comment: You can use Scenarios and Scenario outlines next to each other. Delete it?

Comment: Or add the example from scenario to scenario outline and delete the scenario